# Does 7z or RAR5 offer better resistance to brute force attacks?

Tags: passwords, brute-force, 7zip

Does 7z or RAR5 offer better resistance to brute force attacks?

Comment: Reduced the wordiness

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on hashcat's default benchmarks for each (shown here when run on a GTX 970 GPU - YMMV), it looks like RAR5 is marginally slower (hashes per second), and therefore more resistant to offline attack:

```
---------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 11600 (7-Zip) [Iterations: 16384]
---------------------------------------------
Speed.#1.........:     5801 H/s (87.87ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:4096 Thr:1 Vec:8


--------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 13000 (RAR5) [Iterations: 32799]
--------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:     4478 H/s (55.33ms) @ Accel:512 Loops:1024 Thr:1 Vec:8
```

Interestingly, the RAR3 family appears to be even slower:

```
------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 12500 (RAR3-hp) [Iterations: 262144]
------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:      760 H/s (84.05ms) @ Accel:64 Loops:16384 Thr:1 Vec:8

------------------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 23800 (RAR3-p (Compressed)) [Iterations: 262144]
------------------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:      709 H/s (89.64ms) @ Accel:64 Loops:16384 Thr:1 Vec:8

--------------------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 23700 (RAR3-p (Uncompressed)) [Iterations: 262144]
--------------------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:      770 H/s (83.00ms) @ Accel:64 Loops:16384 Thr:1 Vec:8
```

What's not clear to me is whether the default work factors (iterations) can be customized for these file formats. If any can, they could be made more difficult to attack.

Comment: But isn't the number of iterations used by 7z equal to 524288 (2^19 ) ?